# Select all labels inside element except inside one div

Tags: css

Trying to select all labels inside an element except labels inside one child div. Tried two approaches but nothing seems to be working

```
.parentDiv *:not(.skipLabelsParent) label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

This is failing because * selects all parents including child elements of `skipLabelsParent` class and parents of labels inside.

```
.parentDiv label:not(.skipLabelsParent label) {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

I am not sure why this is failing.

Any solutions other than this?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reddyp/gjaozryL/2/) here

> **The fiddle contains just an example of situation. Don't take that as final case. Labels could be anywhere and at any level. I just want to
>   skip inside every skipLabelsParent class. I made that very clear in my
>   question. Please read question again and provide generic solution.
>   Else I will look for other approach.**

Comment: Can you make a code snippet or a fiddle of this please?

Comment: `.skipLabelsParent label { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px}` Why not just override it below.

Comment: @thepio Updated fiddle

Comment: @Sarcoma Parent Div styling contains generic styling for label inside app. But the container I am loading is not part of the application and has individual styles for each and every label. Its very dirty to manually override in my case. Tried that.

Comment: Could you clarify which ones need to be red in you example?

Comment: @Sarcoma Only first label in fiddle

Comment: Would this be too messy? https://jsfiddle.net/gjaozryL/16/

Comment: @Sarcoma Its just solution for this example. I am looking for a generic solution for a fat ass application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you want, is to do some intelligent re-styling of the labels you want to skip with a good selector:

```
.parentDiv .skipLabels{/*your css here*/)
```

and style the child div with that selector.  This would be the least amount of work.

Next, depending on how many labels we're talking about, is to add the class directly to the labels you want to skip so that the following code would skip the `<label>`'s with the class `.skipLabels`:

```
.parentDiv label:not(.skipLabels) {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

If that isn't gong to work for you, then I think you should just override the the child div's styling right under the parent divs:

```
.parentDiv{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.skipLabels{
    display: .....;
    margin-bottom: ....;
}
```

This way, you can put the `.skipLabels` class anywhere and you will know the styling will take effect like you want.

Comment: Finally settled down with similar solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is not working because you cannot chain selectors in `:not` yet http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Currently you can only use “simple selectors”

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors

This works for example:

HTML:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <label>Pnoe</label>
  <div>
    <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>
    <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>
    <div>
        <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parentDiv label:not(.skip) {
  color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gjaozryL/19/

Whereas this selector breaks all together:

HTML:

```
<label>Pnoe</label>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <label>Pnoe</label>
  <div>
    <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>
    <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>
    <div>
        <label class="skip">Pnoe</label>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label:not(.parentDiv .skip) {
  color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gjaozryL/20/

Comment: Finally settled down with similar solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can define

```
.parentDiv > label{
  color: red;
}
```

Thanks to the ">"-operator, only elements that are **direct** children of the element before are selected. In your case only the first label "Pnoe".

Answer (score 0):

Given this nested `div`/`label` fragment:

```css
div:not(.skipme) > label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <label>Pnoe</label>
  <div>
    <label>Pnoe</label>
    <label>Pnoe</label>
    <div>
      <label>Nested Phoe</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skipme">
    <label>skip me</label>
  </div>
  <div class="somediv">
    <label>Phoe</label>
    <div class="another-div">
      <label>Phoe</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, have a look at my answer.